# Michio Kaku: Global Symmetry on Yang-Mills theory and gravity theory uniqueness (?)

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills

In p.6 of Michio Kaku book Introduction to Superstrings and M-Theory-Springer (1998), he said

> Yang-Mills theory and gravity theory are the unique solution to two simple geometric statements:

> 1. Global Symmetry -
>    The free theory must propagate pure ghost-free spin-l and spin-2 fields transforming as irreducible representations of $SU(N)$ and the Lorentz group.

> 2. Local Symmetry -
>    The theory must be locally $SU(N)$ and generally covariant

My question is that how can Kaku refer the irreducible representations of $SU(N)$ and the Lorentz group and the spin-l and spin-2 fields as global Symmetry for Yang-Mills theory and gravity theory? Shouldn't the Yang-Mills theory and gravity theory be regarded as gauge theory (with Local gauged) without any global Symmetry?

Kaku also mention the local Symmetry which is gauged but not a global Symmetry. So I suppose Kaku really mean Global Symmetry (not Local Symmetry) of Yang-Mills theory and gravity theory?

Comment: YM has both global and local $SU(N)$ symmetry (you might say local symmetry implies global symmetry but this is strictly speaking not true). The local symmetry is an unphysical symmetry, i.e. it does not act on any physical state. The global symmetry is physical and gives rise to conserved currents and charges (such as color charge in QCD). Everything I've said holds for GR as well.

Comment: To follow up on @PraharMitra's comment, see "asymptotic symmetry group."

Comment: "The global symmetry is physical and gives rise to conserved currents and charges (such as color charge in QCD. Everything I've said holds for GR as well." --> so what are the global symmetries precisely -- could you write an answer for YM and GR?

Comment: @annmariecœur For YM, the global symmetry group is the gauge group ($SU(3)$ for QCD and $SU(N)$ in the example Kaku is presenting). In GR, the global symmetry group is the asymptotic symmetry group of the spacetime (The BMS group for asymptotically flat spacetimes and the conformal group for asymptotically AdS spacetimes).

Comment: What is a good ref to digest BMS and conformal symmetry in a single paper? both are global not gauge symmetry? also can they be dynamically gauged?

Comment: You can look up the study of BMS in these recent lecture notes on the subject https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448. The study of asymptotic symmetries in AdS was perhaps originally done in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01211590.